# How do we return a value of collection view that is inside of tableview cell?

Tags: swift, tableview, collectionview

I have a table view cell that has a collection view inside of it, and i wanted to make a static method i can use from outside the class to get the value but i can not do that
what is an alternative way to return size of this collection view inside the table view cell

What I did is i stored a property with collection view height but couldn't return it in func

Comment: Why don't you just get a value from the dataset?

Comment: what data set @ElTomato

Comment: Can you accept my answer if it helps with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. One of the simplest ways it to use protocols.

In your CollectionViewCell but outside of your class, define protocol:

```
protocol CollectionViewCellDelegate: class {
    func sizeOfCollectionView(size: CGSize)
}
```

In your CollectionViewCell class; define this protocol as a weak variable

```
weak var delegate: CollectionViewCellDelegate?
```

In your CollectionViewCell class; where you have the correct size; return it to any observers of this delegate using the following method:

```
self.delegate?.sizeOfCollectionView(size: bounds.size)
```

Now this delegate receives `sizeOfCollectionView` calls and it's parent can observe it.

For example:

In your parent class:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

After doing this try to build the project and Xcode will tell you that your class doesn't have the delegate implemented. You can then define the delegate as follows:

```
 extension ParentClass: CollectionViewDelegate {
    func sizeOfCollectionView(size: CGSize) {
       // You will receive size here
    }
 }
```

[Here](https://medium.com/@astitv96/passing-data-between-view-controllers-using-delegate-and-protocol-ios-swift-4-beginners-e32828862d3f) I'm also adding a medium tutorial for a more detailed explanation on this.

Hope these help!